# UILabel returns nil

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    var pickerViewYears: UIPickerView!
    var pickerViewMonths: UIPickerView!
    var pickerViewDays: UIPickerView!
    var showDateLabel: UILabel!

    var years = [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
    var months = [01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12]
    var days = [01 ,02 ,03 ,04 ,05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10 ,11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerViewYearsSetting()
        pickerViewMonthsSetting()
        pickerViewDaysSetting()
        showDateLabelSetting()
    }

    func pickerViewYearsSetting() {
        pickerViewYears = UIPickerView()
        pickerViewYears.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
        pickerViewYears.center.x = view.center.x - 100
        pickerViewYears.center.y = view.center.y
        view.addSubview(pickerViewYears)
        //pickerViewYears.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.5).CGColor

        pickerViewYears.dataSource = self
        pickerViewYears.delegate = self
    }

    func pickerViewMonthsSetting() {
        pickerViewMonths = UIPickerView()
        pickerViewMonths.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
        pickerViewMonths.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(pickerViewMonths)
        //pickerViewMonths.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.5).CGColor

        pickerViewMonths.dataSource = self
        pickerViewMonths.delegate = self
    }

    func pickerViewDaysSetting() {
        pickerViewDays = UIPickerView()
        pickerViewDays.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
        pickerViewDays.center.x = view.center.x + 100
        pickerViewDays.center.y = view.center.y
        view.addSubview(pickerViewDays)
        //pickerViewMonths.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.5).CGColor

        pickerViewDays.dataSource = self
        pickerViewDays.delegate = self
    }


    // returns the number of 'columns' to display.
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1

    }

    // returns the # of rows in each component..
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView == pickerViewYears {
            return years.count
        }
        else if pickerView == pickerViewMonths {
            return months.count
        }
        else {
            return days.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        if pickerView == pickerViewYears {
            return "\(years[row])"
        }
        else if pickerView == pickerViewMonths {
            return "\(months[row])"
        }
        else {
            return "\(days[row])"
        }
    }

    func showDateLabelSetting() {
        let selectedRowYears = pickerViewYears.selectedRowInComponent(0)
        let selectedRowMonths = pickerViewMonths.selectedRowInComponent(0)
        let selectedRowDays = pickerViewDays.selectedRowInComponent(0)
        showDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 100)
        showDateLabel.center.y = view.center.y + 150
        showDateLabel.center.x = view.center.x
        showDateLabel?.text = "\(years[selectedRowYears]) \(months[selectedRowMonths]) \(days[selectedRowDays])"

        view.addSubview(showDateLabel)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


}
```

I am trying to create 3 pickerViews to select a year, a month, and a day. And there is a label `showDateLabel` which is supposed to show the result (like 2019 4 21).

When running simulator,

```
thread 1: 
exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_i386_invop,subcode=0x0)
```

always shows in `func showDateLabelSetting()` part. And I have tried running simulator without the label part and it can run properly. Also It says

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

in the debug area just that I am not sure what to do about it.

This is what in the debug area (I am still not sure which part is the useful info so I copy paste it all here)

Left part

```
    self    
    PickerViewPractice001.ViewController    0x00007fdcabc250e0  
    UIKit.UIViewController  
    UIViewController        
    pickerViewYears UIPickerView!   0x00007fdcabd42300
    pickerViewMonths    UIPickerView!   0x00007fdcabd3f460
    pickerViewDays  UIPickerView!   0x00007fdcabd3f8c0
    showDateLabel   UILabel!    nil None
    years   [Int]   20 values   
    months  [Int]   12 values   
    days    [Int]   31 values   
    selectedRowYears    Int 0
    selectedRowMonths   Int 0
    selectedRowDays Int 0
```

Right part

```
2015-09-04 10:13:49.439 PickerViewPractice001[50739:3947139] -[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid height value 100.0 pinned to 162.0 
2015-09-04 10:13:49.439 PickerViewPractice001[50739:3947139] -[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid height value 100.0 pinned to 162.0 
2015-09-04 10:13:49.440 PickerViewPractice001[50739:3947139] -[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid height value 100.0 pinned to 162.0 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

Can anyone tell what is the problem here and how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Is your `showDateLabel` properly connected to the storyboard?

Comment: @ILikeTau This is my first time adding a UILabel programmatically, so I am not sure how to do that. Isn't `view.addSubview(showDateLabel)` means to connect `showDateLabel` to the storyboard? Or what else should I do to connect it?

Comment: I saw that you didn't initialize your `UILabel` and thought that you had done it though the storyboard. Remember that you need it create an object before you can use it.

Comment: @ILikeTau Create an object before using it. Noted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `showDateLabel` has not initialized. Try this:

```
func showDateLabelSetting() {
    let selectedRowYears = pickerViewYears.selectedRowInComponent(0)
    let selectedRowMonths = pickerViewMonths.selectedRowInComponent(0)
    let selectedRowDays = pickerViewDays.selectedRowInComponent(0)
    showDateLabel = UILabel() // Added this line
    showDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 100)
    showDateLabel.center.y = view.center.y + 150
    showDateLabel.center.x = view.center.x
    showDateLabel?.text = "\(years[selectedRowYears]) \(months[selectedRowMonths]) \(days[selectedRowDays])"

    view.addSubview(showDateLabel)
}
```

Comment: Magically, it works! Thanks a lot! Did you figured it out reading the debug area info or you just know the line is always necessary in a UILabel? I want to learn how to find the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You need to initialize the `UILabel` (call its constructor) before you can use it, or else it will be set to `nil`.

Comment: @morphymore You have to initialize any object as @ILikeTau said. And you did not use `IBOutlet` define the label so I think you just forget to initialize it manually.

Comment: @ILikeTau @Bannings So to be clear, `UILabel = UILabel()` and `@IBOutlet` are both initializing the `UILabel`, just the former is used when adding label programmatically and the latter is used when using storyboard. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. The `@IBOutlet` does the initialization and the layout for you.

Comment: @morphymore @ILikeTau I would add that `@IBOutlet` not an initialization method. It just makes a connection which you can access to storyboard or nib via a property. A view will to be initialized if you drag and drop it to storyboard or nib, even thought has not `@IBOutlet`.

Comment: @Bannings So normally when using storyboard to add label I don't need to put in `UILabel = UILabel()` I only need to make sure the label is connected to viewController by control + drag from the storyboard. And when programmatically adding label, I will have to add `UILabel = UILabel()` to initialize the label. Is that correct?

Comment: @ILikeTau and Bannings It makes more sense to me now. Thanks you guys so much!